# React Component is not rerendering on setState

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have following code. I am setting state with setState method (`this.setState({ country: "", offset: "" });`) and Its not causing the `render()` method rerendering by itself.

````
  state = { country: "", offset: "" };
  onClicked = () => {
    console.log("Fine Click away");
    // Get the call back from props
    let country = this.state.country;
    let offset = this.state.offset;
    this.setState({ country: "", offset: "" });
    const callback = this.props.onpress;

    if (callback) {
      callback(country, offset);
    }
  };
getTheCountryName = event => {
    this.setState({ country: event.target.value });
  };
  getTheOffSet = e => {
    this.setState({ offset: e.target.value });
  };
render() {

    const Caption = this.props.caption;
    return (
      <div>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div>Please enter the name of country and offset:</div>
        <input
          placeholder="Name of Country"
          onChange={this.getTheCountryName}
        />
        <input placeholder="offset" onChange={this.getTheOffSet} />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <button className="rectangular-button" onClick={this.onClicked}>
          <div className="caption">{Caption}</div>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}```
````

Comment: Not sure why you are copying the values of state properties.

Comment: How do you know `render` is not called ? You don't display the values in the component's `state`.

Comment: Your code does trigger a `render` call: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-cloud-vv3ob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the state in any capacity will not trigger an update of the input values because you are not actually using your state in the JSX you're returning. The code below will feed the values to the inputs so they are updated when your state is changed. You can read about forms and controlled inputs in React [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html):

```
class App extends React.Component {
   state = { country: "", offset: "" };
  onClicked = () => {
    console.log("Fine Click away");
    // Get the call back from props
    let country = this.state.country;
    let offset = this.state.offset;
    this.setState({ country: "", offset: "" });
    const callback = this.props.onpress;

    if (callback) {
      callback(country, offset);
    }
  };
getTheCountryName = event => {
    this.setState({ country: event.target.value });
  };
  getTheOffSet = e => {
    this.setState({ offset: e.target.value });
  };
render() {

    const Caption = this.props.caption;
    return (
      <div>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div>Please enter the name of country and offset:</div>
        <input
          placeholder="Name of Country"
          onChange={this.getTheCountryName}
          value={this.state.country}
        />
        <input value={this.state.offset} placeholder="offset" onChange={this.getTheOffSet} />
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <button className="rectangular-button" onClick={this.onClicked}>
          <div className="caption">Reset</div>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Clicking the button does trigger a re-render just fine, as you can see in the sandbox I linked in my comment above.

Comment: You're right. To be more accurate, it will not update the values of the inputs.  I've updated my answer.